# Filling new columns in shapefile attribute table

Tags: qgis, shapefile, filling, column

I am faced with a challenge. I have shapefile from the government of Canada and I need to add extra 4 columns to the attribute table from other databases released by the government. How do I fill them automatically?

As after I add the four columns to the attribute table, I need to fill them with the values I have from the other DBs and there is no way I do it one by one; it is over 12000 cells to be filled!

Do you have a suggestion or method that would allow me to stitch these dBs to the shapefile?

Comment: If the tables share a common ID field you can use the Join Field tool in ArcMap.

Comment: That is awesome! it worked on QGIS as well! Thanks man

Comment: Please add a tag for the software you are using.